# Objective c How to convert UIImage to NSUrl

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdata, nsurl

In my app I have an image getting from image picker. And I need to share that image in form of NSURL.

I tried as follows

Convert image to NSData
and convert that NSData to NSURL.

```
UIImage *postImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sahredIcon.png"];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(postImage, 1.0);

NSString *yourstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:your Data Name encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // Or any other encoding method
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:yourstring];
```

I causes null string exception and app crashes

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initWithString:relativeToURL:]: nil string parameter'
```

Is there any way to convert UIImage to NSUrl perfectly & directly

Comment: So you are converting the image data into a URL?  That's pretty creative.

Comment: Why do you need that? Do you want an url as reference to .png asset?

Comment: it is not possible. Nsurl is a link . so you have to store this image into that link

Comment: why dont you just save that image on server & share that link. you iphone can not work as a server.

Answer (score 4):

You can't hold an UIImage in an `NSURL` object.Please note that an `NSURL` object represents a URL that can potentially contain the location of a resource on a remote server, the path of a local file on disk, or even an arbitrary piece of encoded data.

If you are looking for the Asset url, try this

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)UIPicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *) info
{
    NSURL* localUrl = (NSURL *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
}
```